# Magento 2 How to added languages packs to git repo?

Tags: magento2, language-package

I needed to add languages packs to own bitbucket repo. Installed this packs successfully but when I try to add thems to git , git give me message

> "modified content". Spend some time to figured where is issue and found [next] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726131/git-add-a-is-not-adding-all-modified-files-in-directories

**"This error occurs because you have added a folder which is already linked with some another github repository . The parent folder you are working with is linked with some other repository. "**

I decide to delete .git folders , clean cache and tryed to add again needed folders, use `git add .....` , then `git status` say me: "no changes added to commit".

So is there any way to add files to own git repo , or in this case I need to install languages packs only by comands inside project?

```
composer require mageplaza/magento-2-some-language-pack:dev-master
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy sm_SM
```